# Chimera generation rate between mouse and other animals

Tags: stem-cells

I have a question about the chimera generation rate of the mouse compared with other animals.

Before asking the question, I need to define the following terms:
ES cells: Embryonic stem cells

The procedure of generating chimera mice and other chimera animals should be similar, where I am supposed to do genetic modification, such as gene knockout, on the ES cells and implant them back into the animals' blastocysts. However, I found the following statement interesting:

> The mice's chimera generation rate is higher than that of other animals.

and

> Where chimera production with ESL cells has been attempted, both the rates and the levels of chimerism are typically much lower than found with murine ES cells."

From [Gardner, RL (2014)](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-409503-8.00003-2) *Pluripotent Stem Cells from Vertebrate Embryos: Present Perspective and Future Challenges.*

I am not sure why that is the case. Could anyone kindly give some directions? Thank you.

Comment: where did the statement come from? Did it provide a reference?

Comment: "Where chimera production with ESL cells has been attempted, both the rates and the levels of chimerism are typically much lower than found with murine ES cells." From Pluripotent Stem Cells from Vertebrate Embryos: Present Perspective and Future Challenges. ESL cells from other animals are very, very similar to murine stem cells. The only difference is the higher nuclear-cytoplasm ratio compared with the murine ES cells.

Comment: I am editing your question to include the relevant quotation and citation